# How to use drilldown chart correctly?

Tags: charts, yii, highcharts, yii2, drilldown

I have made this highcharts multiple drilldown by typing manually. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Vf3yT/1107/. But, I need to make chart which its data taken from database. I have searched from google and the other questions from stackoverflow, but I still do not get the answer. People asked about drilldown problems that their data manually typed to their highcharts code and it's different than my question because I took data from database.

Here is the table that I'm gonna put to my chart:

**facultyin2011**

[image]

**department2011**

[image]

**major2011**

[image]

Here is my codes:

**Controller**

```
        $faculty = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Faculty'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $age1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $age2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();


        $age1 = array_map('floatval', $age1);
        $age2 = array_map('floatval', $age2);


        $data['ageforfacultystudent'] = json_encode($faculty);
        $data['age1'] = json_encode($age1);
        $data['age2'] = json_encode($age2);



        $department = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Department'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agedepartment1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agedepartment2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();


        $agedepartment1 = array_map('floatval', $agedepartment1);
        $agedepartment2 = array_map('floatval', $agedepartment2);


        $data['agefordepartmentstudent'] = json_encode($department);
        $data['agedepartment1'] = json_encode($agedepartment1);
        $data['agedepartment2'] = json_encode($agedepartment2);




        $majorstudent = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['major'])
            ->from('major2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agemajor1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agemajor2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();


        $agemajor1 = array_map('floatval', $agemajor1);
        $agemajor2 = array_map('floatval', $agemajor2);


        $data['ageformajorstudent'] = json_encode($majorstudent);
        $data['agemajor1'] = json_encode($agemajor1);
        $data['agemajor2'] = json_encode($agemajor2);
```

**index**

```
$(function () {

    // Create the chart
    $('#containers').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Basic drilldown'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: $ageforfacultystudent
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                name: 'lessthan25',
                data: $age1,
                drilldown: 'department1'
            },
            {
                name: 'btween25to29',
                data: $age2,
                drilldown: 'department2'
            }],

        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'department1',
                name: 'Departemen',
                data: [{
                    name: 'lessthan25',
                    data: $agedepartment1,
                    drilldown: 'major1'
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'btween25to29',
                    data: $agedepartment2,
                    drilldown: 'major2'
                }
                ]
            }, {

                id: 'major1',
                data: $agemajor1
            },
            {

                id: 'major2',
                data: $agemajor2
            }]
        }
    })
});
")?>
```

I want to make first level chart is faculty, second is department and third is major.

The result of my codes above is like this picture below:

[image]

the problem of my chart above: the chart can't be drilled down because I still do not put the drilldown codes. I don't know how to put it because the data that I took is from table in database. Could anybody please help me to solve this? What may I do to fix that problem? It would help me a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: What will be first level and second level in drilldown (database data)

Comment: first level is faculty, second level is department, and third level is major @Deep3015

Comment: Is there any problem with Highcharts library or is this only a problem with data?

Comment: there is no problem with the highchrts library. I just don't know how to code drildown chart that retrieve data from database @KacperMadej could you please help me to make the drilldown?

Comment: @Deep3015 here is the link https://pastebin.com/QvzxWzkC

Comment: oh yeah. Here is the link https://pastebin.com/S8enGwCA

Comment: I think with the existing data you provided it is not possible to create drilldown chart.  http://jsfiddle.net/rhhh2sg3/  and follow comments

Comment: but when I typed the data manually, the drilldown could work. Look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/rhhh2sg3/1/  @Deep
but I don't know how to make the drill down if I take data from database

Comment: correct you have to process php variables into suitable array of objects,similar to series to your drill down static data example

Comment: but I don't know how to make it since I'm a newbie @Deep3015

Comment: @dewinataria Please post exemplary data set you are able to provide to JavaScript for the Highcharts chart. From that format you will need to parse it to the format required by Highcharts - e.g. like data format in any working JSFiddle demo for drilldown in comments or from official Highcharts demos.

Comment: Here is my data example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vf3yT/1107/
I use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vf3yT/1107/) by typing manually. But all I need is to make highcharts that the data taken from database @KacperMadej

Comment: @dewinataria You are creating chart in JavaScript, right? So data needs to be there - in JS - at some point, so I am asking what is the data format you are possible to bring there. The best option would be to provide the format that is used in the manual typing JSFiddle demo. If you need help with JS - client side - parser to change data format, then I could help.

Comment: my data format is in Yii2 structure. I have controller and view. I want to make a chart that from the chart we're able to know how many people who have age less than 25, between 25 and 29. I've posted the data (from the table that I've posted) in my question above  @KacperMadej

Comment: @dewinataria Create your series and drilldown.series arrays in the controller and later in JS load as `series: $series, drilldown: { series: $drillSeries } ` - this is server side solution. Client side would be to store the loaded variables in JS before using in Highcharts and check their sizes to determinate what should the structure of the series and drilldown.series arrays should be, but this is possible to do server side which is more efficient.

Comment: do you mean like this https://pastebin.com/TM2z7jcN (controller) and https://pastebin.com/yaiRaMSp (view) ? @KacperMadej

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139764/discussion-between-kacper-madej-and-dewinataria).

Comment: yeah of course @KacperMadej

Comment: could you please check my chat? Because sometimes, the chat notification doesn't appear @KacperMadej